# Magento 2 swagger error

Tags: magento2, swagger

while accessing https://website-url/swagger got error as

**500 : {"message":"Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5f33c4d0d4891"} https://website-url/rest/all/schema?services=all**

Then I checked into exception log

[2020-08-11 11:20:13] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5f327eeda2f5a; Message: Class "decimal" does not exist. Please note that namespace must be specified. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-5f327eeda2f5a; Message: Class "decimal" does not exist. Please note that namespace must be specified. at /var/www/html/website/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:205, LogicException(code: 0): Class "decimal" does not exist. Please note that namespace must be specified. at /var/www/html/website/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php:139)"} []

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have an doc block somewhere in an Api interface that either has a parameter declared with type  decimal or a return type decimal. `@param decimal $...` or `@return decimal`. You should use `float` for it.

Comment: could you explain to me where can I find a doc. I am totally new to this. -@Marius

Comment: I don't know which one is. It's probably a custom file. just look in files for the texts I highlighted in the anwer